# Inline Class Functions that have private data members

Tags: c++, oop, class, function, inline

Now I have been learning about inline functions and I encountered something that really made me confused

See this class

```
class Nebla{
private:
    int x;
public:
    inline void set(int y){x=y;}
    inline void print(){cout<<x<<endl;}
};
```

it has a private data member: `int x;`

And it has two public inline functions: `set(int y)`  and `print()`

Now since they two functions are inline, when they are called the compiler replaces the function call with the contents of the function.

So if I do this

```
Nebla n;
n.set(1);
n.print();
```

since the two functions are inline, It should be the equivalent of this:

```
Nebla n;
n.x=1;
cout<<n.x<<endl;
```

but wait a second, `x` is private. Therefore, this shouldn't work.

But it does and I'm confused why it does work although normally you cant access private members from outside the class?

Can anyone explain to be why you can access private data members from outside the class but when a member function is inline it can although inline just replaces the function call  with the contents of the function?

Comment: Inlining doesn't just do `n.x=1;`. Your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Data member protection is purely *conceptual*. It exists only at the compiler level. It is checked and enforced when the compiler translates the source code. Once the code is compiled, there's no difference between public and private data members anymore, i.e. there are no physical mechanisms that would enforce access control and prevent access to private data members.

Member access is enforced by the compiler in accordance with the language specification. The language specification states that class member functions (regardless of whether they are inline or not) have access to private members of the class. So the compiler allows that access. Meanwhile, other functions are prohibited such access, so the compiler complains about it.

In your example you are accessing private data member from a member function. That is allowed, so the code compiles, i.e. the compiler does not complain. What happens later in the generated machine code, after the function gets inlined, is completely irrelevant. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Do you have a reference to prove what you are saying?

Comment: @Mohamed Ahmed Nabil: It is like asking me for a reference that 2+2=4. On the one hand, of course, I have a reference: the language specification or virtually any basic book on C++. On the other hand, this is so very basic that it is difficult to even begin choose the best reference in this case. Just think of myself as that reference :)

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: You can convince yourself by interleaving `private`, `protected`, and `public` data members and looking at their addresses. You can convince yourself by returning pointers to `private` data members from functions and then manipulating them through those pointers.

Comment: to add on, it is not mandatory for a compiler to inline a function if the keyword "inline" is present in the signature.

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand how inline works. The compiler inlines the *logic* of the code, not the actual *text* of the code.

> Can anyone explain to be why you can access private data members from outside the class but when a member function is inline it can although inline just replaces the function call with the contents of the function?

Because the contents of the function are the *contents of the function*. They don't stop being the function just because they've been inlined. You are allowed to access private member variables from inside a member function. When a member function is inlined, its code is still inside the member function because the *function* is inlined.

Comment: Hmm.. That kinda explains it thanks. I guess the explanation in my book isnt clear enough

Comment: It's not the contents of the function that are inlined but the *meaning* of the function. (That is, its behavior.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, whether or not it gets inlined is up to the compiler. In a lot of cases it will decide is not the best thing to do.

Second, in the case it does inline it, it does so with a compiled binary, product of the behavior described in the C++ source code, not the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

Morbo says the inline keyword doesn't work that way.

Morbo says that the inline keyword says that symbol conflict at linker time involving this function should be ignored, and that all functions whose implementation is within the declaration of the class are implicitly inline.

Morbo is wise.  You should listen to Morbo, even if there is a minor technical additional meaning of inline that involves taking addresses.

More seriously, inline just let's you put definitions of the implementation into a header file.  Actually making the code inline is thus easier because it doesn't have to happen at link time (and most C++ linkers are too lazy) but it does not cause the code to be inline.

And finally privacy is conceptual, it is not enforced by the C++ run time.  It is just enforced at compile time by telling you that something is out of bounds.

Comment: Hello, Morbo. How's the family?

Comment: Morbo says Belligerent and numerous.